# bash: trying to get all the files with a specific extension

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

Hi I am trying to work on the files which have an extension like this *.p8,*.p16,*.p32.

```
./pack_vectors $@
for var in "$@"
do
if [ -f $var ];
then
pack_list="${var/.dat/.p}"
echo $pack_list
# below line doesn't work
for f in $pack_list+([:digit:]);do
```

what i am getting out is:

```
./wrapper.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 ./wrapper.sh: line 10: `for f in $pack_list+([:digit:]);do'
```

Why?

Comment: Try **ls *.p[0-9]\***

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do is to use `find`:

`find . -name "*.p8" -o -name "*.p16" -o -name "*.p32`

The `-o` is the equivalent of boolean `OR`

To assign it to a variable, do this:

`myvar=$(find . -name "*.p8" -o -name "*.p16" -o -name "*.p32")`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of possible issues. You have to have `extglob` on if you want to do the regex-style file matching you're trying to do in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). So put

```
shopt -s extglob
```

before your for loop. You're also looking for `[[:digit:]]` if you want to use the posix character class in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). So putting that together, try

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in ".p"+([[:digit:]]); do
```

Not quote sure what "$pack_list" is so replaced it with ".p" above.

Comment: for f in $pack_list+([[:digit:]]);do


gets me:


./wrapper.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./wrapper.sh: line 9: `for f in $pack_list+([[:digit:]]);do'

Comment: @user3306484 What is `$pack_list`?

Comment: It is working now like this:
    for f in "$pack_list+([[:digit:]])"; do

Comment: @user3306484 Probably some word-splitting issues. If you don't want word-splitting performed on them you need to quote variables in bash "$pack_list". The rest can can be left unquoted.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, a bit of changing of BroSlow answer:

```
for f in "$pack_list+([[:digit:]])"; do
```